# Why is there space between navigation bar top and safe area top despite constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

At runtime, you can see a ~20px space between the status bar bottom and the top of the navigation bar:

[image: simulator]

The constraints of the navigation bar:

[image: constraints]

Comment: In Attributes inspector - View Controller section. try to select-unselect Adjust Scroll View Insets and then check.

Comment: set controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`

Comment: automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets looks to be deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of below code to Hide Navigationbar

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware that the navigation bar was already there -- instead of hiding, I just updated the existing navigation bar.